# Not able to use the Toggle Switch with if else conditions in swift ui

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, toggle

I am not able to access use the switch. I want if the switch is on, it should come up with a text field and if it is off the value of the variable should be zero. Can anyone help me with this. I have tried to use two different methods. One by using .Onchange and one without using .Onchange. When I use .Onchange, it comes up with a waning that the result of text field is unused. And when I don't use .onAppear it doesn't accept (userSettings.load = 0) but the text field works fine then. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.The variables are defined as :

```
struct TwoView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
    @State var load: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    Toggle("Casual loading", isOn: $load)
                        .onChange(of: load) { value in
                            if load == false
                            {
                                userSettings.loadrate = 0
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                TextField("Casual Loading", value: $userSettings.loadrate, format: .number)
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var loadrate = Float()
}
```

Comment: If you format your code, it'll be easier you you and potential answers to parse it and give you a good answer.

Comment: @jnpdx done it. There are two files. I have copied the code and pasted it. The issue I am facing is when I use the toggle without on change it only accepts the textfield and doesn't allow me to assign a value to userSettings.loadrate = 0. When I use .onchange it allows me to assign the value userSettings.loadrate = 0 but comes up with a warning Textfield is unused.

Comment: Hmm -- that really doesn't look formatted to me. In Xcode, you can select you code and use `ctrl-i` to get it to format for you. Then, you can remove extraneous empty lines by hand.

Comment: @jnpdx I think you can still copy this code in your Xcode and check the results.  So that it is easy to access I have copied the codes in separate sections. Please let me know if you can help sort this code. Thanks

Comment: It's not about being able to copy and paste it to see the results (although that part is definitely good!) -- it's about being able to quickly see the issue and then being able to fix it easily to provide an answer, which someone will likely have to do in order to modify your code easily. I've done the formatting for you in this case so that you can see. With the formatting, it's easier to get a good answer. Without it, not only do you run the risk of people skipping over the question, but you may also get downvoted for it.

Comment: @jnpdx Amazing. Thank you for all your help. You are a genius.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. You can mark the answer as correct/accepted by clicking the green checkmark next to it.

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks, did it. Amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're using `TextField` outside of the view hierarchy, and just inside the `onChange`. In fact, as you mentioned, Xcode is giving you a warning about the fact that it is unused.

To solve this, you can use an `if` clause inside the hierarchy itself:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        TwoView().environmentObject(UserSettings())
    }
}

struct TwoView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
    @State var load: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    Toggle("Casual loading", isOn: $load)
                        .onChange(of: load) { value in
                            //only imperative, non-View hierarchy code should go in this block
                            if load == false
                            {
                                userSettings.loadrate = 0
                            }
                        }
                    if load { //<-- Here
                        TextField("Casual Loading", value: $userSettings.loadrate, format: .number)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class UserSettings: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var loadrate = Float()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TextField is a view element and it shouldn't be inside a closure. It should be a child of a view.
Similarly, assignment is not a view element, so it is not accepted to be in a view.

So, what you need to do is put `userSettings.loadrate = 0` into `.onChange`, and put `TextField` outside `.onChange`.

I'm not sure what exactly is your expected result, but here is an example.

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        Form {
            Toggle("Casual loading", isOn: $load)
                .onChange(of: load) { value in
                    // Assignment should be inside a closure
                    if load == false {
                        userSettings.loadrate = 0
                    }
                }
            if load == true {
                // View element should be a child of a view.
                TextField("Casual Loading", value: $userSettings.loadrate, format: .number)
            }
        }
    }
}
```